# set property or class attribute according to value from machine.config

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to set attribute value [] for class or property based on machine.config field ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Attributes are metadata that are baked into the assembly at compile time. This means that everything that you pass as values to attributes need to be constant and known at compile-time. Files such as machine.config are read at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly because attribute parameters/values have to be constant.

You can, however, write a custom attribute or inherit from the one you are working with to load the value at runtime.